# How to extract differences in field values between records with the same values in a specific field

Tags: sql, database

I have a table like the example below (just with 200+ columns):

```
+-------+-----------+-------+------+
| id    | field1    | field2| ...  |
+-------+-----------+-------+------+
| 1984  | test      | 55    | ...  | 
| 1984  | test      | 56    | ...  |
| 2006  | sky       | 13    | ...  |
| 2006  | sky       | 13    | ...  |
| 2006  | dog       | 13    | ...  |
| 1364  | house     | 77    | ...  |
| 1364  | garden    | 33    | ...  |
| ...   | ...       | ...   | ...  |
+-------+-----------+-------+------|
```

I am looking for a way to create a query/report that would show me:

- The fields which have different values but
- only within the "group of records" that have the same "id".

So something like:

```
+-------+-----------+
| id    | diff      |
+-------+-----------+
| 1984  | field2    |
| 2006  | field1    |
| 1364  | field1    |
| 1364  | field2    |
| ...   | ...       |
+-------+-----------+
```

If I could achieve this, it would be super helpful.
Getting the values for the different fields would be a bonus.

I wanted to ask if this would be achievable with SQL? What Methods/Functions should I look into to build such a query?

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: What is your database? also please clear your requirement more.

Comment: it's a .csv extract that I receive and I have Oracle and Postgres available to load it into and run SQL

Answer (score 0):

I think `union all` seems like the simplest method:

```
select id, 'field1' as col
from t
group by id
having min(field1) <> max(field1)
union all
select id, 'field2' as col
from t
group by id
having min(field2) <> max(field2)
union all
. . .
```

You can construct the query using a spreadsheet or by writing a query on the metadata tables in your database.